# PHP MySQL display multiple rows grouped by common fields

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I'm trying to figure out how to list COMPANY 's CATEGORY 's and BRAND 's, where the layout would look similar to this:

**COMPANY 1**

- CATEGORY 1:
  *BRAND X

  BRAND Y

  BRAND Z*
- CATEGORY 2
  *BRAND A

  BRAND B

  BRAND C*
- CATEGORY 3
  *BRAND A

  BRAND X*

I'm not familiar enough with PHP + MySQL to find the right SEARCH and PHP output in order to achieve this.

My table looks similar to this:

```
COMPANY   | CATEGORY   | BRAND    
--------------------------------
Company 1 | Category 2 | Brand A  
Company 1 | Category 2 | Brand B  
Company 1 | Category 2 | Brand C  
Company 1 | Category 1 | Brand X  
Company 1 | Category 1 | Brand Y  
Company 1 | Category 1 | Brand Z  
Company 1 | Category 3 | Brand A  
Company 1 | Category 3 | Brand X
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    some_table
  ORDER BY
    company,
    category,
    brand
") 
or trigger_error('Query failed in '. __FILE__ .
   ' on line '. __LINE__ .'. '. mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
  $companies = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $companies[$row['company']][$row['category']][] = $row['brand'];
  }

  foreach ($companies AS $company => $categories) {
    echo '<h2>'. htmlentities($company, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') .'</h2>';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($categories AS $category => $brands) {
      echo '<li>'. htmlentities($category, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
      foreach ($brands AS $brand) {
        echo '<br><em>'. htmlentities($brand, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') .'</em>';
      }
      echo '<br>&nbsp;</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
  }
}
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/apotu3/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Just Fetch everything and put it in a hash in php, something along the line of

```
$rs = mysql_query("Select * from myTable");
$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $results[$row['COMPANY']][$row['CATEGORY']][] = $row['BRAND'];
}
```

`$results` would contain data structure like

```
array(
    'Company 1' => array(
        'Category 1' => array('Brand X', 'Brand Y')
... etc
)
```

try `var_dump($results)` to make more sense out of it