# Using phpmyadmin, how would I store a range of data in a database? (Utilising a many to many relationship)

Tags: php, mysql

I need to make a database containing information on pharmaceutical drugs.

- Column one is the unique identifier field with auto-increment. e.g., "1"
- Column two contains the name of the drug. e.g., "Tramadol"
- Column three contains a list of weights. e.g., "30g , 40g , 50g , 60g"

Using a php while loop and an array, I could echo this data using the following method:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "Drug Name: {$row[1]} Drug Weights: {$row[2]}"
}
```

While this would work, I know it is definitely not the best way. The list of weights would have to be a varchar, rather than actual individual integers. What would be the best way to store and echo a range of information for a single product, as seen in column three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a many-to-one relationship, as you have multiple dosage amounts in relation to a single drug: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships/

As for your problem, this depends on the context of how you want to use the data. If the dosage amounts are meant to be used as reference to the various products offered at the pharmacy (i.e. a small bottle of Tramadol and a large bottle), then I would probably just add a new row for every dosage amount, as you will probably have a limited set of values to choose from in the first place, and it's more representative of what a store's inventory would look like. You could then iterate through it with nested loops like this:

```php
$drugs = array()
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $drugs[$row['name']][] = $row['dosage_amount']
}
foreach ($drugs AS $drug => $dosages) {
    echo '<h2>'. htmlentities($drug, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') .'</h2>';
    foreach ($dosages AS $dosage) {
        echo '<br><em>'. htmlentities($dosage, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') .'</em>';
    }
}
```

Reference: [PHP MySQL display multiple rows grouped by common fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337639/php-mysql-display-multiple-rows-grouped-by-common-fields)

On the other hand, if it's used to track prescriptions, then have a separate table along the lines of `id | drug_id | dosage_amount`, along with any other information you would require.

If you went with the second option, you would use an `INNER JOIN` to get the required data:

```sql
SELECT drugs.name, prescriptions.dosage_amount
FROM drugs
INNER JOIN prescriptions
ON drugs.id=prescriptions.drug_id
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

From there, you can iterate through it the same way you were doing it already:

```php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "Drug Name: {$row[0]} Drug Weight: {$row[1]}"
}
```

Comment: Hi Joel, do you reckon you could elaborate a bit more on the first option? Each drug only has 3 - 4 sizes each, but the number of sizes varies. Many just have 1 size, for example. How could I echo each drug's name on a webpage, and under each name, echo all of their sizes?
Would I have to implement two loops in my database query, one to echo all of the drugs, and another loop to echo all the sizes of each drug?

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "Drug Name: $row[drugName] Drug Weights: $row[drugWeights]";
}
```

You didn't indicate the names of your columns, so I'm guessing.

---

Please do not use [`ext/mysql`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) in new code.  Switch to `PDO` or `mysqli`.